# Can shared library call another shared library?

Tags: android, shared

Can one shared library load and call functions from another shared library?

I have Shared library **libDsmTestLib.so** that use another shared libraries **libDsmShared.so** and **libPINDsmShared.so**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := DsmTestLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := DSM_Library.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lDsmShared
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lPINDsmShared

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

when I create **libDsmTestLib.so** and want to use it in my android java application like this:

```
package com.dsm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class dsmTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
      
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("DsmTestLib");
        }
        catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) {
             System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
        }
    }  
}
```

In the catch block I get error

> Cannot load library: link_image[1962]:
> 33 could not load needed library
> 'libDsmShared.so' for
> 'libDsmTestLib.so'
> (load_library[1104]: Library
> 'libDsmShared.so' not found)

Loadlibrary function cant find library **libDsmShared.so** that uses my main library **libDsmTestLib.so**, Who can tell why ? and what can I do to solve this problem ?

---

#### Additional Information

I had a static library (.so written in C++) with functionality which I want to use from my Java android application, for that I create .cpp and .h files in which I call the function from the previously created library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NDK - How to use a generated .so library in another project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669220/ndk-how-to-use-a-generated-so-library-in-another-project)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

#### [I found this and test it](http://markmail.org/message/awqkjurr2xd4cuun):

The Android dynamic linker had a bug that prevented this from working,
but
was fixed in 1.6, I believe.
If you use the NDK, use "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libB libC" when
defining
the libA module.
This assumes that libB and libC are also NDK modules that were generated
with the NDK.

```
In case libB.so and libC.so are not generated with the NDK, you should do
the following:
```

- in the libA module definition, use LOCAL_LDLIBS +=
  /full/path/to/libB.so /full/path/to/libC.so
  this ensures that correct symbol exports are generated in libA.so
- manually copy libB.so and libC.so to $APP_PROJECT/libs/armeabi
  before
  rebuilding your .apk,
  this ensures that it will be copied to /data/data//lib at
  installation time by the package manager.

#### now Android.mk have this look:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := DsmTestLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := DSM_Library.cpp


#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := DsmShared
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += PINDsmShared


# Set local libs with full path.                                                                
LOCAL_LDLIBS := C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libDsmShared.so           
LOCAL_LDLIBS += C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libPINDsmShared.so        

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

#### but now error

> Cannot load library: link_image[1962]:
>   33 could not load needed library
>   'C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libDsmShared.so'
>   for 'libDsmTestLib.so'
>   (load_library[1104]: Library
>   'C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libDsmShared.so'
>   not found)

occurred, but when I check C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libDsmShared.so this path I found that the library exists there ... What's the metter ?

Answer (score 7):

I found solution in this way - explicity loading libraries:

```
    static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("DsmShared");
        System.loadLibrary("DsmTestLib");
    }
    catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) {
         System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved at leased my problem and is exactly what is written in the first Chapter of the Overview of the NDK-Documentation, but I forgot the first lines I read until I finally got my code to compile in the NDK without errors. (<android-ndk-r6b>/docs/OVERVIEW.html respectively <android-ndk-r6b>/documentation.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error . This is how i solved it and maybe you should try this method.

`LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libutils.so`

Comment: It's not -L it should be -l and you should use -lutils and not use the whole path. I'm looking at what people is doing by adding just $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libutils.so that for me is like statically linking the lib into your own project/library.

Answer (score 1):

No, Android VM will search the so file in its own file systems, but not a folder as `[C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib]` (I think).

It will search for it from the `@androidvm:/system`, or other folders specified by java.library.path.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lutils
```

Also don't forget copying `libutils.so` into your `libs/armeabi` folder

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I just discovered after a long debugging session that the order in which load lib does matter.

```
    System.loadLibrary("libDsmShared");
    System.loadLibrary("libPINDsmShared");
    System.loadLibrary("DsmTestLib");
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First, your Activity have to load all the shared libraries

   ```
   static {
       try {
           System.loadLibrary("libDsmShared");
           System.loadLibrary("libPINDsmShared");
           System.loadLibrary("DsmTestLib");
       }
       catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) {
           System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Include the "lib*.so" when compiling your native code (in the Android.mk) as in

   ```
   ...
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/cygdrive/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libDsmShared -lDsmShared
   LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/cygdrive/home/android-ndk-r5b/samples/testingDsm/lib/libPINDsmShared -lPINDsmShared
   ...
   ```