# how to process android ndk project dependency

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have two android projects with native support, that's to say,  they're both android project and c++ project. One is android library(**app-lib**), another(**std-pos-app**) is android app who depends app-lib.

The Android.mk file in **app-lib** like bellow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := app-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When it's builded, it will produce libapp-lib.so in libs/armeabi fiolder.

**std-pos-app** want to call the native code in **app-lib.so**. So the Android.mk file in **std-pos-app** like bellow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#------------------
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := app-lib1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to-libapp-lib/libapp-lib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#------------------

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := std-pos-app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Use **PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY** to prebuild **libapp-lib.so**, when **std-pos-app** is builded, libapp-lib.so and libstd-pos-app.so will appear in libs/armeapi. But when I want to run the **std-pos-app**, the error occured:

> Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi/libapp-lib.so

I konw the reason why it happen, because the android project dependency. **But how to solve it?** Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alike thread that describes the same question. And I've solved the problem with the solution in the thread. [How to use a library project with both c and java apis on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510162/how-to-use-a-library-project-with-both-c-and-java-apis-on-android?rq=1)