# How to fix the error "Unused source files" in an android 6.0.1 NDK project which uese multiple prebuilt c libraries

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use some c shared libraries in my android application.
The project structure is like:

```
project
  |
  |---app->main.cpp, Android.mk
  |
  |---lib->|->Android.mk
           |
           |---include----|
           |              |---mylib->a.h, b.h ...
           |
           |---libs-> libX.so, libY.so, libZ.so
```

In the main.cpp, I use the header files like:

```
#include <mylib/a.h>
#include <mylib/b.h>
```

In the /project/app/Android.mk, I have

```
LOCAL_PATH             := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE           :=  my_application
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := the_libX_1_0_0 the_libY_1_0_0 the_libZ_0_0_9
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := main.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In the /project/lib/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                := the_libX_1_0_0
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES            := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libX.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                := the_libY_1_0_0
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES            := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libY.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                := the_libZ_0_0_9
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES            := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libZ.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

***[The build error]***
When I try to make the application, the error I had:

```
including ./Android.mk ...
build/core/binary.mk:1345: *** project/lib/Android.mk: the_libX_1_0_0: Unused source files: project/lib/libs/the_libX_1_0_0.so.
build/core/ninja.mk:155: recipe for target 'out/build-aosp_arm.ninja' failed
make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Error 1
```

---

AOSP environment:

- PLATFORM_VERSION := 6.0.1
- PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION := 23
- PLATFORM_JACK_MIN_SDK_VERSION := 24

Development environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- GCC 5.4

---

A bit more background about the question:
Actually, the library libX, libY and libZ are libcrypto.so, libssl.so and libc.so. Google uses a shrunk version of OpenSSL, I am working on an application requires the OpenSSL. So I am trying to use pre-built OpenSSL libraries here.

References: 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html#dm
[Android NDK/JNI: Building a shared library that depends on other shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922736/android-ndk-jni-building-a-shared-library-that-depends-on-other-shared-librarie)
http://www.scriptscoop3.com/t/84e1c84496bc/android-difference-between-local-export-c-includes-and-local-c-includes.html

Comment: I am facing the same problem. May I know if you have fixed it ?

Comment: I could resolve it using LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc.                                            [click here for more info](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)