# NDK: using user created .so when trying to build another .so

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link some .so that I generated using the NDK to a new .so I'm trying to create,
as the old .so contains definitions of functions that I want to use in the new .so.

I've tried this Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := prog_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c 
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += mylib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,<tag>) # with and without
```

I've also tried this method I found in stackoverflow [NDK - How to use a generated .so library in another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669220/ndk-how-to-use-a-generated-so-library-in-another-project/5735507#5735507) but still no succes as I get always  : 
**prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lmylib.so**

I really appreciate any help to solve this issue.
B.R

Comment: name problem ? -lxxx will look for libxxx.so

Answer (score 0):

you have to use include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) instead of include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)